# Why does Kif appear at the end of "Where No Fan Has Gone Before"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, futurama

In the closing credits of "Where No Fan Has Gone Before" (*Futurama* Season 4, Episode 11) we are shown a collection of stills that appeared in the show, to the sound of a variant of the Star Trek theme. The last still is this one of Kif Kroker, which breaks the trend:

[image]

Kif *did* appear in the episode during the inquiry / trial conducted by Zap Brannigan, but nowhere in the episode did he appear like that.

**Was it a shout out to the puppet used by Balok<sup>1</sup> to intimidate others?**

If not that (and I'm not convinced it was), then what is the relevance of that portrayal of Kif?

[image]

<sup>1</sup>Balok's puppet appeared in "The Corbomite Maneuver" (Season 1, Episode 10) of the original Star Trek.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## Shout-out to Balok

This most certainly harks back to the Balok puppet based on the fact that, for at least one whole season of *The Original Series*, a still of the Balok puppet appeared in the closing credits of every episode, despite not appearing in those episodes:

[image]

Given the similarity of Kif's appearance, it seems they inserted him at an analogous position in the closing credits.

As further evidence, notice also that **the background behind Kif (a circuit pattern) is virtually identical to the one behind the Balok** in the closing credits still:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes, the circuit pattern / appearance at end of closing credits (no wonder it jumped so easily to my memory) seems to clinch it. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Glad to be of help. :-)